# Remove the first Divider in a SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui

I got a simple list that iterates through some values from my database:

```swift
List {
    TextField("Search", text: $textFieldSearch)
        .padding(7)
        .background(Color(.systemGray6))
        .cornerRadius(8)
    
    ForEach((bookViewModel.books).filter({ "\($0)".contains(textFieldSearch) || textFieldSearch.isEmpty })) { book in
        NavigationLink(destination: ChapterView(book: book), label: {
            
            HStack {
                Text("\(book.name)")
                
                
            }
            .padding()
        })
    }
}
.onAppear {
    bookViewModel.fetchBooks()
}
```

What bothers me is that a border is just above the `TextField` - which I assume is because I put it inside `List`. However, if I move `TextField` to be above `List`, it just eats the entire screen and doesn't show the `ForEach` part at all - also  it doesn't "conform" to the same style. What is the best approach here?

[image: lightmode border]

Comment: The better way is putting TextField out of List on top!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### iOS 15+

The `.listRowSeparator(_:)` View modifier was introduced for iOS 15 and above. So you can use it like follows,

```
List {
    TextField("Search", text: $textFieldSearch)
        .
        .
        .
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden) // <-- Set it as hidden

    ForEach(list.indices) { int in
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

The result:

[image]

#### iOS 14

For iOS 14 you can use a `LazyVStack` embedded in a `ScrollView`. As the name states, a `LazyVStack` is lazy, meaning that it will load the items only when needed, similar to a `List`. So you can use it as an alternative. I made a demo with the following code,

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var textFieldSearch: String = ""

    var list = [
        "hello",
        "there",
        "general",
        "kenobi"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                TextField("Search", text: $textFieldSearch)
                    .padding(7)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                ForEach(list.indices) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(list[index]), label: {
                        VStack {
                            index > 0 ? Divider() : nil // Showing the divider for all items after the 0th index
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(list[index])").foregroundColor(.black)
                                Spacer() // Spacer to right align the Text
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal) // Setting horizontal padding
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not using iOS15 :(

Comment: I've changed the answer to include ios 14

Comment: For anyone looking in 2024, you can simply use .listStyle(.plain) for the button style. This is backwards compatible down to iOS 13.